# Problems writing a script that outputs first 100 palindromic primes

Tags: ruby

I wrote this script to find the first 100 primes that are also palindromes. For some reason some primes are not being printed (13, 17, etc.), and the palindromic function does not seem to work. Any tips?

```
#palindrome checker
def is_palindrome?(number)
    number == number.to_s.reverse.to_i
end


#primes will consists of all primes starting with 2
#i will be incrememented and each i will be checked for being prime
primes = [2]
i = 3

#we only want the first 100 palindromic primes
while primes.length < 100
    #test is false for a prime
    test = false
    #checks if i is divisible by any of the elements in the array
    primes.each { |n| 
        if i % n == 0
            test = true
        end
    }
    #if i is prime that it is added to the primes array
    if test == false
        primes.push(i)
    end
    i += 1
end

#remove all non palindromic primes 
primes.each { |n|
    if is_palindrome?(n) == false
        primes.delete(n)
    end
}

#puts palindromic primes
puts primes
```

Comment: In what way does it not seem to work? Why would it print those primes (not being palindromes)? Also, it looks like it will get the first 100 primes, then remove those which are not palindromes (leaving you with fewer than 100 in the list).

Comment: It doesn't work in that many primes are included that aren't palindromes. You're right about the second part, I noticed that after submitting the question. @iamnotmaynard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by changing your script to this:

```
#palindrome checker
def is_palindrome?(number)
    number == number.to_s.reverse.to_i
end


#primes will consists of all primes starting with 2
#i will be incrememented and each i will be checked for being prime
primes = [2]
i = 3

#we only want the first 100 palindromic primes
while primes.length < 100
    #test is false for a prime
    test = false
    #checks if i is divisible by any of the elements in the array
    primes.each { |n| 
        if i % n == 0
            test = true
        end
    }
    #if i is prime that it is added to the primes array
    if test == false
        primes.push(i) if is_palindrome?(i) # This is the line I changed
    end
    i += 1
end


#puts palindromic primes
puts primes
```

You were getting weird errors by modifying and iterating over your the `primes` array at the same time.  I moved the palindrome check to inside the while loop so you will actually get 100 palindromes vs. 100 primes minus the non-palindromes.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I'd write it:

```
require 'prime'

is_palindrome = -> i { i.to_s == i.to_s.reverse }
puts Prime.lazy.select(&is_palindrome).take(100).to_a
```

Simple, clear, concise.

The output is:

```
# 2
# 3
# 5
# 7
# 11
# 101
# 131
# 151
# 181
# 191
# 313
# 353
# 373
# 383
# 727
# 757
# 787
# 797
# 919
# 929
# 10301
# 10501
# 10601
# 11311
# 11411
# 12421
# 12721
# 12821
# 13331
# 13831
# 13931
# 14341
# 14741
# 15451
# 15551
# 16061
# 16361
# 16561
# 16661
# 17471
# 17971
# 18181
# 18481
# 19391
# 19891
# 19991
# 30103
# 30203
# 30403
# 30703
# 30803
# 31013
# 31513
# 32323
# 32423
# 33533
# 34543
# 34843
# 35053
# 35153
# 35353
# 35753
# 36263
# 36563
# 37273
# 37573
# 38083
# 38183
# 38783
# 39293
# 70207
# 70507
# 70607
# 71317
# 71917
# 72227
# 72727
# 73037
# 73237
# 73637
# 74047
# 74747
# 75557
# 76367
# 76667
# 77377
# 77477
# 77977
# 78487
# 78787
# 78887
# 79397
# 79697
# 79997
# 90709
# 91019
# 93139
# 93239
# 93739
# 94049
```

Comment: Nice use of `lazy`, Jörg. +1

Comment: Beautiful thing I've learned here! `take` and `select` working together lazily.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the internal workings, but deleting elements from an array over which you are iterating will cause it to skip things. E.g.:

```
>> arr = %w{John Paul George Ringo}
=> ["John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo"]
>> # Print each one out; delete if it contains "o"
>> arr.each {|e| puts e; arr.delete e if e =~ /o/}
John
George
=> ["Paul", "Ringo"]
```

didn't even evaluate `Paul` or `Ringo`.

You should use [Array#delete_if](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-delete_if):

```
primes.delete_if { |n| !is_palindrome?(n) }
```

However, more specifically to your question, you can just put the `is_palindrome?` check in the loop which builds your array, eliminating the need for the second filtering loop (and allowing you to build the list of the 100 palindromic primes you want).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
primes.each { |n|
    if is_palindrome?(n) == false
        primes.delete(n)
    end
}
```

You're iterating over `primes`, and inside the block modifying it. That's very error prone.

Try doing:

```
primes.each { |n|
    if is_palindrome?(n)
      puts n
    end
}
```

Also, you could write your code a lot better, to make it more readable, and you could use a more efficient algorithm to calculate the prime numbers, like the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs some TLC. Here's how I'd do it:

```
#palindrome checker
def is_palindrome?(number)
  number == number.to_s.reverse.to_i
end


#primes will consists of all primes starting with 2
#i will be incrememented and each i will be checked for being prime
primes = [2]
i = 3

#we only want the first 100 palindromic primes
while primes.length < 100

  #checks if i is divisible by any of the elements in the array
  primes << i unless primes.any? { |n| i % n == 0 }

  i += 1
end

#remove all non palindromic primes
primes.delete_if { |n| is_palindrome?(n) == false }

#puts palindromic primes
puts primes
```

Which, when run, outputs:

```
# >> 2
# >> 3
# >> 5
# >> 7
# >> 11
# >> 101
# >> 131
# >> 151
# >> 181
# >> 191
# >> 313
# >> 353
# >> 373
# >> 383
```

`primes.delete_if { |n| is_palindrome?(n) == false }` could be written more succinctly as:

```
primes.delete_if { |n| !is_palindrome?(n) }
```

Or, do away with stripping `primes` and calling `is_palindrome?` and use a simple `reject`:

```
puts primes.select{ |n| n == n.to_s.reverse.to_i }
```

which reduces the code to:

```
#primes will consists of all primes starting with 2
#i will be incrememented and each i will be checked for being prime
primes = [2]
i = 3

#we only want the first 100 palindromic primes
while primes.length < 100

  #checks if i is divisible by any of the elements in the array
  primes << i unless primes.any? { |n| i % n == 0 }

  i += 1
end

#puts palindromic primes
puts primes.select{ |n| n == n.to_s.reverse.to_i }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another use of Ruby's prime number generator:

```
require 'prime'

e = Prime.each
100.times {begin i = e.next end until i.to_s == i.to_s.reverse; puts i}

2
3
5
7
11
101
131
151
181
191
313
353
373
383
727
...
```

Here [Prime#each](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html#method-i-each) is a prime number generator that responds to `next`:

```
e.class = Prime::EratosthenesGenerator
```

Alternatively,

```
i = e.succ
```

Comment: You can remove `begin..end`.. Is it needed ? I don't think so. `i = e.next until i.to_s == i.to_s.reverse` is Ok.

Comment: The problem is that `i = e.next` must be executed first.  Try it.  I'd love to find a further simplification.

Comment: Then place one line `i = e.next` before,`#times`. Then no need `begin..end`.

Comment: I considered that, but don't like it as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
is_palindrome = -> (i) { i.to_s == i.to_s.reverse }

def prime?(number)
  flag = true

  (2..number/2).each do |n|
    if (number%n) == 0
      flag = false
      break
    end
  end

 flag
end

palindromic_primes = -> (length) do 
  2.upto(Float::INFINITY).lazy.select { |x| is_palindrome.call(x) && prime?(x)  }.first(length)
end

puts palindromic_primes.(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

This one line code will give an array of first 100 palindrome prime numbers.

```
require 'prime' 
p Prime.each.lazy.select{|x| x.to_s == x.to_s.reverse}.first(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I write the solution:

```
require 'prime'

def palindrome?(number)
  number == number.reverse
end

def palindrome_prime(n)   
  final = []
  num =2
  while(num)
    if (Prime.prime?(num) && palindrome?(num.to_s))
      final.push(num)
      if (final.length == n)
        print final
        return final
      end
    end
    num += 1
  end   
end

p palindrome_prime(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some Organised code here, also takes care of performance issues. More readable and reusable. Might help someone.

`#method to check prime number
  def is_prime?(n)
    2.upto(n/2).each do |x|
      return false if n % x == 0
    end
    true
  end`

`# Method to Check if given string is palindrome using recursion.
  def is_palindrome_rec?(str)
    return true if str.length == 0 || str.length == 1
    return false if (str[0] != str[-1])
    return is_palindrome_rec?(str[1..-2])
  end`

`# Method to return palindromic primes using lazy load. It works first N palindromic primes.
 def palindromic_primes(n)
    2.upto(Float::INFINITY).lazy.map { |x| 
      x if (is_prime?(x) && is_palindrome_rec?(x.to_s)) }.select { |x| x.is_a? 
      Integer}.first(n)
  end`

`#Pass N here as parameter. In your case it will be 100.
 result =  s.palindromic_primes(25)
 print result`

`#OUTPUT --> [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 101, 131, 151, 181, 191, 313, 353, 373, 383, 727, 757, 787, 797, 919, 929, 10301, 10501, 10601, 11311, 11411]`

Answer (score 0):

For people landing here after being frustrated by timeouts, try changing the order of check (check whether the number is palindrome or not)

```rb
n = gets.to_i

prime = ->(num) { (2..(num**0.5).floor).none? { |i| (num % i).zero? } }
palindrome = ->(num) { num.to_s == num.to_s.reverse }

palindromic_primes = ->(n) do
  2.upto(Float::INFINITY).lazy.map do |x| 
    x if palindrome.(x) && prime.(x)
  end.reject(&:nil?).first(n)
end

print palindromic_primes.call(n)
```